# JQuery hide <tr> based on <td> id

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I would like to hide some table row from my table based on the table data id, I've only found ways to hide the table row based on the table data value but that is (in my case) not the solution.

For example, lets say this is my table:

```
<table id='table1' border="1">
<tr id='hideme'>
<td id='letmehide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td id='letmehide'>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id='donthideme'>
<td id='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td id='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What should my javascript/JQuery look like?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twyqS/

Comment: Bogers dont use duplicate ids

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take into account that ids must be unique on your page so I recommend you to use css classes instead of ids

**HTML**

```
<table id='table1' border="1">
<tr class='hideme'>
<td class='letmehide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td class='letmehide'>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class='donthideme'>
<td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#table1 .hideme').hide();
```

This would allow you to hide several rows if necessary.

Comment: Ok that is one solution, but I would like the JQuery to hide the first row based on the td id 'letmehide' if that's possible.

Comment: instead of an id, I recommend you to use css classes

Answer (score 2):

First of all is you're using jQuery, use it to attach your event handlers. It results in much more semantic HTML, and is a better separation of concerns.

With regard to your problem you should use the `:first` selector to get the first `tr` element, and then the `hide()` function:

```
$('#table1 tr:first').hide();
```

Alternatively you could use the `id` of the `tr` as it is intended to be unique:

```
$('#hideme').hide();
```

I would suggest familiarising yourself with the jQuery API, specifically the [selectors available](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#table1 tr[id="hideme"]').hide();//in table1 hide tr that are with attribute id="hideme"
```

Answer (score 1):

**[ID of an element should be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute), so use class attribute instead of ID in your elements**

Try

```
<table id='table1' border="1">
    <tr class='hideme'>
        <td class='letmehide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td class='letmehide'>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='donthideme'>
        <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$('#table1 tr:has(td.letmehide)').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rDdSL/)

Answer (score 1):

`$("#letmehide").parent().hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('#table1 tr:first').hide();
    });
});
```

And see this...

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twyqS/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

For others who want to use the same ***id*** for multiple ***tr*** 
Try This:

```
$(this).closest("tr").hide();
```

Comment: This assumes that `this` is passed.