# HTML show hide <tr> based on id (increment)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table structure where the 1st tr is always shown and the rest is hidden:

```
<table>
    <tr>
     <td></td>  // No id always show
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
     <td style="display:none;"></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
     <td style="display:none;"></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
     <td style="display:none;"></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
     <td style="display:none;"></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
     <td style="display:none;"></td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show" /></td>
<input type="button" id="hide" value="hide" /></td>
```

I want to show the hidden tr based on there id.  Let say user click show, tr id=2 will show, user click show again tr id=3 will show.  Hide button will hide 
the last tr id that is currently shown which is tr id = 3.

I'm checking some of the questions/answers here but none so far fits my question:

[JQuery hide <tr> based on <td> id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233348/jquery-hide-tr-based-on-td-id)

[Showing/Hiding Table Rows with Javascript - can do with ID - how to do with Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518035/showing-hiding-table-rows-with-javascript-can-do-with-id-how-to-do-with-clas)

I'm just started doing front end and still new to javascript and jquery so any example or help is much appreciated?

Comment: I see only your `<td>` table data/cell is hidden, so you want to show the `<td>` ?

Comment: I didn't put any elements inside <td>  as I see its irrelevant since hiding the <tr> will also hide the elements inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id_num = 0;                                    // define the id number
  $('#show').on('click',function(){
      id_num++;                                      // add +1 to the id number
      $('#' + id_num).show(); // show tr with that id
  });
  $('#hide').on('click',function(){
      $('tr:not(:nth-child(1)):visible:last').hide(); // hide the last visible tr but not the first one
      id_num = $('tr:visible:last').attr('id') ? $('tr:visible:last').attr('id') : 0;                      // check for tr id when hide if this isn't the first return id number if not return 0
  });
});
```

```css
tr[id]{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>first</td>  // No id always show
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
     <td>1</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
     <td>2</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
     <td>3</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
     <td>4</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
     <td>5</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show" /></td>
<input type="button" id="hide" value="hide" /></td>
```

Comment: May I ask why the tr[id]{
  display : none;
} is seperated from the other code?

Comment: @ArnoldCristobal This is the css selector `tr[id]` this mean select all tr with id attribute instead of typing `#1,#2,#3,#4,#5{display : none;}` .. separated because its a css code you may link your css stylesheet (.css file) to your html if not you can use this code inside `<style></style>` in your html page

Comment: Thank you,  I learned something from you about css selector. :)

Comment: @ArnoldCristobal You're welcome .. and you can read about selectors here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 .. good luck :-)

Comment: Quick question if I can ask, can a table id be added to this?  I'm planning to use 2 tables with the same function.

Comment: @ArnoldCristobal No, id should be unique so don't duplicate id .. if you need 2 tables you can use classes instead

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var trIndex = 0;

document.getElementById("show").onclick = function() {
  if(trIndex === 5) return;
  trIndex += 1;
  document.getElementById(trIndex).style.display = "table-row";
};

document.getElementById("hide").onclick = function() {
  if(trIndex === 0) return;
  document.getElementById(trIndex).style.display = "none";
  trIndex -= 1;
};
```

```css
tr:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>0</td>  // No id always show
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
     <td>1</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
     <td>2</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
     <td>3</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
     <td>4</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
     <td>5</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show" /></td>
<input type="button" id="hide" value="hide" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button:

```
<input type="button" id="show" value="show" onclick="showHidden()"/>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show" onclick="hideVisible()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function showHidden() {
  $("td:hidden").first().show();
}

function hideVisible() {
  $("td:visible").last().hide();
}
```

Be carefull with the rest of the elements, you might want ot use something like td.someclass and then td class="someclass".

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$("show").on("click",function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(count > 5)
        return;
    count++;
    $("#"+count).show();    
})

$("#hide").on("click",function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(count<=0)
        return;
    $("#"+count).hide();
    count--;
})
```